# Binomial distribution: what is the probability of getting exactly 3 women from a draw of Y = 1 to 10?

Tags: probability, combinations, negative-binomial

So my question is **We choose a certain number Y of different people**

1. what is the probability of getting exactly 3 women from a draw of Y = 1 to 10 ?
2. what is the probability of getting at least more women than men from a draw of Y = 1 to 10

Consider the following: there are **45 people, 38 men and 7 women**

1. I tried for example when Y = 1; P(3 women) = 1C3 * (7/45)^3 * (38/45)^-2

edit: Y = 3 would work in my eyes, and everything above Y = 3 until Y = 10, but under Y = 3 wouldnt be possible in my opinion, or am i wrong there?

my question now is, would that be correct? I have never calculated something like this with a negative exponent. Consider that 1C3 doesnt work..

2. I tried for example Y = 10; 1 - P( most more women than men) = 1 - 10C3 * (7/45)^7 * (38/45)^3 , but that doesnt look correct in my opinion..

Comment: [https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think certain things should be cleared up before answering.

If the extraction happens with replacement (which I assume), then the **binomial** distribution expresses the probability of having $k$ successes in $Y$ trials.

In question $1$, if success is the event "extracting a woman" (happening with probability $p$) then the probability of the  event in the question is

$${Y\choose{k}}p^k(1-p)^{Y-k} = {10\choose{3}}\left(\frac{7}{45}\right)^3\left(\frac{38}{45}\right)^7$$

Why? Because there are ${10\choose{3}}$ possible ways of extracting exactly 3 women and 7 men out of 10 draw (this is the crucial point, the draws are 10!), and the probability of said event does not change.

As for problem 2, try considering all the possible ways in which the event "more women than men have been extracted" can happen. Note that the events "6 women and 4 men", "7 women and 3 men" ecc... are all mutually disjoint, and so you can apply the law of total probability easily.

**Addendum**

I strongly suspect that the question being asked in point 1 and 2 is asking what the probability of said events is out of 10 draws. However, let's suppose the question actually refers to all possible number of draws from 1 to 10.

If you look carefully at the formula I have written above, it states the probability of having $k$ successes in $Y$ trials.

Suppose we are dealing with $Y=4$. In what ways can I have more women than men in this number of draws? Well, I could have 0 men and 4 women or 1 man and 3 women. These two events happen with respective probability

$${4\choose{4}}\left(\frac{7}{45}\right)^4\left(\frac{38}{45}\right)^0$$

$${4\choose{3}}\left(\frac{7}{45}\right)^3\left(\frac{38}{45}\right)^1$$

These events are disjoint for any given experiment, so the probability of their union is the sum of their probabilities. Adding them up, we get the desired result.

For each number of draws, you have to make the same considerations. This looks like a rather daunting and tedious exercise, so I would suggest checking if the question was rather not

> What is the probability of getting at least more women than men from 10 draws?

Comment: So that would be 10C3 * (7/45)^3 * (38/45)^7, which would be equal to = 0.1383042114 = 13.83 % , right? but this works only when Y = 10, what if Y = 1? that is what i dont understand yet...

Comment: Yes, I believe 0.1318... would be right. If you have only one draw (if this is what you mean when you say $Y=1$), then the probability of extracting exactly 3 women is surely 0 (there is not way of extracting 3 women if you have only 1 draw).

Comment: as for problem 2, I would only need to do for example 1C1 * ( 7/45)^1 * (38/45)^0 + 2C2 * ( 7/45)^2 * (38/45)^0 + 3C3 * ( 7/45)^3 * (38/45)^0 + 4C4 * ( 7/45)^4 * (38/45)^0 + 5C5 * ( 7/45)^5 * (38/45)^0 +6C6 * ( 7/45)^6 * (38/45)^0 + etc... , right?

Comment: (for problem 1) yes exactly, if Y = 1 then you cannot draw 3 women, for Y = 1 and Y = 2 the result is 0, for Y = 3 it is 13.83% and for the rest for example Y = 6 it would be 6C3 * (7/45)^3 * (38/45)^3, am i right?

Comment: No. I have added some clarifications in the answer.

Comment: ah i see, so this will be a big one... unfortunately, the question is as already mentioned, here i will copy& paste the entire question here:
We choose a certain number Y of different people
1)- calculate the probability of getting exactly 3 women from a draw of Y = 1 to 10

2)- calculate the probability of getting at least more women than men from a draw of Y = 1 to 10

Comment: for problem 2 , maybe it is meant to do the probabilities one by one, for example when Y = 1 it would be 1C1 * ( 7/45)^1 * (38/45)^0, then for Y = 2 it would be 2C1 * ( 7/45)^2 * (38/45)^0 then for Y = 3 it would be 3C1 * ( 7/45)^3 * (38/45)^0 + 3C2 * ( 7/45)^2 * (38/45)^1 and so on, or ?

Comment: but at Y = 8 and above, wouldnt that be impossible since there are at most 7 women to draw ?

Comment: Almost! If you draw say 9 people, there is still a positive probability of drawing more women than men (for example, 7 women and 2 men) but indeed some options are excluded (you can't draw 8 women and 1 man), so you have to consider that too.
Also, watch out! When you have 2 draws, the condition is satisfied also when you draw 2 women and 1 man (that is also a possibility) and this happens with probability ${2\choose{1}}(7/45)(38/45)$, which you should add to the sum. Also, check your evaluation for $Y=3$ (you should have $3\choose{0}$, not $3\choose{1}$ in the first summand).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86933/discussion-between-larry-and-easymode44).